# Zebra printer prints zpl code instead of label

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, cups

Zebra printer is connected to CUPS server and I am sending prints using IPP. When I parse zpl file and fill data using a parser it prints correctly, but when I directly try to print zpl with data using IPP it just prints it as plaintext.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I was able to solve the issue. The problem was that the printer was not set to accept the raw zpl and print it. I had to set the printer to raw and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone still facing this issue here are the steps we followed to setup the ZPL printer.

1. Start the cups server and access the web interface via http://localhost:631/
2. Add printer
3. Choose your local printer (your printer should be listed)
4. press continue
5. Provide name, description and enable the share checkbox
6. continue
7. Choose the Make as 'RAW' please refer to the attached snapshot.
   [image]
8. Add the printer.
   It should print the label instead of raw ZPL.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using a generic text based print driver to print the ZPL.